# Pyramid - Dynamically assign template to view

Tags: python, pyramid

In Pyramid, templates are statically assigned to view with

```
@view_config(renderer='templates/foo.pt')
def my_view(request):
    return {'foo':1, 'bar':2}
```

However, in some cases, we want to set different template for each user. For example, `user1` use templates from `templates/style1/xxx.pt` and `user2` use templates from `templates/style2/xxx.pt`. Thus, we need a way to dynamically pass templates to views, instead of configure them statically.

Is there anyway to do the task elegantly?

Comment: I think this is related http://stackoverflow.com/q/6553569/242786

Answer (score 3):

I just did this a couple of days ago.

Here is example code for an ajax call.

```
@view_config(name="my_view", renderer="")
def my_view(request):

    renderer = choose_renderer()            #this is where you would dynamically choose what renderer you want. ex "templates/foo.pt"
    data = get_my_data_for_renderer

    return render_to_response(renderer, data, request)
```

Here is an example for a normal route call

```
    @view_config(route_name="my_view", renderer="")
def my_view(request):

    renderer = choose_renderer()            #this is where you would dynamically choose what renderer you want. ex "templates/foo.pt"
    data = get_my_data_for_renderer

    return render_to_response(renderer, data, request)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution gonna work, and it is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6553569/242786. However, it make the code redundant because every view must contain some lines to get the render and return with `render_to_response()`. I am looking for a elegant solution which can keep `@view_config` mostly unchanged, only make `renderer` to be a pattern or a relative path.

Comment: I added a new answer that might help

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. I have not tested it. I'm pulling from memory :)

Add this to your **init**.py in your config settings.

```
 config.add_route('my_view', 'my_view/{renderer}')
```

Use this view:

```
 @view_config(route_name='my_view', renderer='')
 def my_view(request):
    renderer = request.matchdict['renderer']
    data = get_my_data_for_renderer()
    return render_to_response(renderer, data, request)
```

Comment: Yep, with this solution, every view still has redundant `renderer = request.matchdict['renderer']`. Currently I am digging into the implementation of `view_config` to see if I can set `renderer` as a pattern, like `renderer='template/{styledir}/main.tpl'` to get the task done. In this case, no more redundant code is needed in view logic.

Comment: I'm not sure what to you mean by redundant code. Maybe you should put more examples what you want to do in your question.  May even adding views dynamically at server start up could solve your problem.